# Вывод данных из google таблицы на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-spreadsheet

Я делаю сайт свой первый сайт и сейчас работаю над страницей вывода предстоящих мероприятий. Я хочу реализовать вывод актуальных данных из Google Sheets на страницу сайта.

В таблице есть массив данных в виде строк с информацией о предстоящем мероприятии. Колонки следующие:
Дата, Время, Организатор, Название, Описание, Участники, Тип мероприятия, Ссылки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая последующая строка заполняется необходимыми данными. Далее мне нужно вывести события на ближайшую неделю и визуально кастомизировать эти данные. После завершения события (когда дата мероприятия останется в прошлом и станет неактуальной) строка исчезала с сайта, и данные вновь отображались на неделю вперед. Надеюсь, что я ясно смог описать свою задачу.

Каким образом можно вывести данные из таблицы на сайте?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. Воспользуйтесь API или опубликуйте Таблицу и берите из нее данные напрямую.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что вопрос получится таким общим. Я хочу использовать таблицу в google как базу данных для вывода информации на моём сайте. Т.е. по сути форма вывода на сайте это такая же таблица в тэге table с такой же структурой, но разница лишь в том, что в гугл таблице могут появляться колонки с технической информацией, комментариями и пр., которые не надо показывать на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

нужно только зайти в гугл документы , файл --> публикация в интернете --> встроить
там будет код его скопируй и вставь на сайт

Comment: На сколько я понял, данный метод не позволяет кастомизировать таблицу, что не подходит под условия задачи